# How Can I Reset This Backbone View on Collection Change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

How can I bind this view to collection change events so that it Resets when a new item has been added to the collection?

```
KAC.Views.ModuleMainNavigation = Backbone.View.extend(
    {
        tagName: "div",
        id: "",
        className: "",
        template: JST['modules/main_navigation'],
        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this);
        },
        events: {
        },
        render: function () {
            this.$el.html(
                this.template(
                    { 
                        collection : this.collection 
                    }
                )
            );

            return this;
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to listen for the change event.
Most of the time this is done in the `initialize` function.

You could either listen for all events (model change, collection reset, new model, model removed):

```
this.collection.on('change reset add remove', this.render, this);
```

Or only for the new model added event:

```
this.collection.on('add', this.render, this);
```

See also [backbone.js collection events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279236/backbone-js-collection-events)